# How to copy two elements of a list into one bigger element?

Tags: c, list, casting, copying

Here's an example :

I have a list of uint8_t element (It's not real code ^^) :

```
List[0] = 0010 1001
List[1] = 0100 0111
```

And have one unsigned short element (Twice the size of uint8_t).

I want my short element to be this after : 0010 1001 0100 0111

Can I move it like this :

```
ShortElement = (unsigned short) UnsignedInt8List[0];
```

Or do I have to use binary tweaks to move it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't simply cast the value. Since `unsigned short` can always represent the value in `uint8_t`, the value will remained unchanged. If you do `ShortElement = (unsigned short) UnsignedInt8List[0];`, `ShortElement` will be assigned the value `0000 0000 0010 1001`.

You should use bitwise operations to combine the values:

```
ShortElement = ((unsigned short) UnsignedInt8List[0] << 8) |
               ((unsigned short) UnsignedInt8List[1] << 0);
```

This is a little more verbose than it needs to be, but I've included everything for clarity. It could be equivalently written as:

```
ShortElement = ((unsigned short) UnsignedInt8List[0] << 8) | UnsignedInt8List[1];
```

---

One note is to be careful with your types. You know the size of `uint8_t`, but you don't portably know that `unsigned short` is exactly 16 bits long, you only know that it must be at least 16 bits long to be able to hold the range [0, 65535]. This isn't a problem in anything you've shown because of that minimum of 16 bits, it's even often recommended to use non-fixed width types where safe and convenient, but it's something to keep in mind.

---

One this that might be tempting but that you should **not** do is to use pointers to get the value:

```
// DO NOT DO THIS, IT IS THE WRONG WAY
ShortElement = *(unsigned short *) &UnsignedInt8List[0];
```

Don't do that, you'll get the wrong result on many systems, and it might outright cause a crash on some. It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: You can't just use hardcoded bit arithmetic, as this hardcoded the CPU architecture you depend on, which was not specified by the OP.

Comment: @liberforce They don't specify that what's in the array is in the CPU byte order. They simply specify that the have 8-bit values that the want to combine in the way specified. The first byte is explicitly shown to be used as the upper 8 bits of a 16-bit value.

Comment: You're right, seeing the OP try to access the array as a short to read the data made me focus on the byte ordering. I'm not allowed to remove my downvote for now, hope to fix that in the future. Thanks for your explanation.